# Ruby on Rails with Unicorn - how to do automated reporting in a threadpool in just one instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

We use Unicorn to run 16 instances of a RoR app. We are implementing automated reporting with the report results emailed and/or ftp'd. The reports can take up to a few minutes to generate and so we use a threadpool.

Since we have 16 instances we don't want to have potentially 16 x #_threads connections into our database. Ideally we would have just once of the instances running the scheduled reports.

I can think of a couple of ways to do it:

1) Have one of the 16 instances somehow distinguishable from the others and this is the only instance that can run the reports. I think that this would require some coding with the unicorn api, or possibly we could use a lockfile or have a database column that has the instance number allowed to run the reports.

The disadvantage of this approach is that the instance will be included in the unicorn load balancing and so users will be on the instance while the reports are being generated. However, if the thread is working properly it shouldn't be an issue.

2) Have a separate unicorn deployment for 1 instance that runs the reports and isn't included in the apache/unicorn connection. No one will interact with this instance via the ui - it just runs the reports.

The disadvantage of this approach is that I have to remember to update this instance when deploying and it's another instance to monitor for problems.

I'd prefer #1 for support simplicity, but I'm fine with #2 too.

Does anyone have experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

I originally went with the approach of using a dedicated reporting instance that ran the reports in a thread pool of size=1 (and later just a plain single thread). It appeared like it would work but when I put it under load testing I quickly found situations where activity in the main thread and the reporting thread would block or cause problems on fetches (like returning nil instead of an array)

I did some research and rails/activerecord 2 (which we're currently on) isn't threadsafe.

So now I'm going to try using the whenever gem to run the reports in a rake process. I had this working for awhile but decided against it because I didn't want to maintain an external cron (even though its configured in the app, which is nice for git).